# How to copy range of cells to a new worksheet based on value in another cell

Tags: vba, excel

Row by row, I need to copy cells in columns A through I if any cell in columns J through N contains the word "Yes". In addition if there is a 'Yes' I also need to copy the column Header name. For example if Column K, Row 3 has a "Yes" then I need all the cells in Row 3 from Column A to I copied to a new worksheet, starting in Column B, row 1 (if it is the first "Yes result"). Column A, Row 1 would be the header name from Column K. I'd need this to run through all the Yes results making a new row on a separate worksheet each time.

Plus every time I run the code it starts blank from scratch again.

Pictures are of what it would look like before and after

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: Hey! Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please post what you tried so we can help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I'm not seeing your issue still. I added some code to handle more data in your workbook. But as you can see in my images I'm returning with multiples for multiple yes's. Copy this code and rerun then post your results please and maybe that will help me understand your issues.

```
Option Explicit
Sub YesToSheet()
Dim r As Long 'Used to loop Rows
Dim totR As Long 'Used to count Rows
Dim c As Long 'Used to loop Columns
Dim dest As Worksheet 'Used for Destination Worksheet
Dim home As Worksheet 'Used for source worksheet
Set home = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set dest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
home.Activate

totR = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
    For r = totR To 2 Step -1
        For c = 11 To 14
            If UCase(Cells(r, c).Value) = "YES" Then
                Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 1).Offset(0, 9)).Copy
                dest.Cells(1, 2).Insert xlShiftDown
                dest.Cells(1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
        Next c
   Next r

   dest.Activate
   totR = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B"))
   For r = 1 To totR
        Cells(r, 1).Value = "Stake" & r
   Next r
End Sub
```

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: Thank you - however that copied data from columns J through N which I don't want (it's important I don't have the entire row copied). Plus it only produced 2 results when I should be receiving 5 for the 5 Yes cells. It also didn't copy the column header of the cell that was 'Yes' to the beginning of the new worksheet

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's copying all the column headers, when I only need one copied to the beginning of each row. It's also still on creating 2 rows when I would expect to see 5 for the 5 Yes cells

Comment: I misspoke. That did help a lot. The only remaining issue is that it's not duplicating when there are two Yes answers in the same row. that's the last missing piece. Would love your help.

Comment: Still struggling here if you could help with those last missing pieces of duplicating when there are two or more Yes answers in the same row